Как добавить в поле input динамическую скидку в value?
<input class="form-control2" name="user_discount"  type="text" placeholder="Знижка" value=" ">

<div class="discount-widjet">
            <p>Ваша знижка</p>
            <p class="input-disc">
                <span id="disc-wid"></span>%
            </p>
        </div>





let discount = () => {
  if (getCookie("disc")) {
    var disc = parseFloat(getCookie("disc"));
    console.log(disc);
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
      if (disc < 4.9999) {
        disc += 0.01;
        setCookie("disc", disc.toFixed(2), {
          secure: true,
          "max-age": 86400,
        });
        jQuery("#disc-wid").text(disc.toFixed(2));
        console.log(disc);
      } else {
        jQuery("#disc-wid").text(5);
        console.log("Максимальная скидка");
        clearInterval(timer);
        return false;
      }
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    setCookie("disc", 0, { secure: true, "max-age": 86400 });
    disc = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
      disc += 0.01;
      if (disc < 4.9999) {
        setCookie("disc", disc.toFixed(2), {
          secure: true,
          "max-age": 86400,
        });
        jQuery("#disc-wid").text(disc.toFixed(2));
        console.log(disc);
      } else {
        console.log("Максимальная скидка");
        clearInterval(timer);
        jQuery("#disc-wid").text(5);
        return false;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  function setCookie(name, value, options = {}) {
    options = {
      path: "/",
    };

    //if (options.expires.toUTCString) {
    // options.expires = options.expires.toUTCString();
    //}

    let updatedCookie =
      encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);

    for (let optionKey in options) {
      updatedCookie += "; " + optionKey;
      let optionValue = options[optionKey];
      if (optionValue !== true) {
        updatedCookie += "=" + optionValue;
      }
    }

    document.cookie = updatedCookie;
  }

  function getCookie(name) {
    let matches = document.cookie.match(
      new RegExp(
        "(?:^|; )" +
          name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, "\\$1") +
          "=([^;]*)"
      )
    );
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
  }
};
export default discount;


скорее всего так же, как и всегда: найти в DOM нужный элемент по его атрибуту,
а потом заменить значение нужного атрибута


document.querySelector('[name="user_discount"]').setAttribute('value','100');
<input class="form-control2" name="user_discount"  type="text" placeholder="Знижка" value=" ">



